# Parse request header properties in middleware, for specif route - ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

As you can see in the following code example, the request body and user-agent are two different parameters of the method, we assign the user-agent into our parsed body object after we receive them.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Launch")]
    public IActionResult Launch([FromBody] LaunchRequestDto launchRequest,
                                [FromHeader(Name = "User-Agent")] string userAgent)
    {
        try
        {
            launchRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;

            //......
        }
    }
```

What would be the correct way to assign the user-agent into our "body object" before, with a middleware maybe. The idea is to have only our ""LaunchRequestDto" as a parameter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the properties of your model by using the `[FromHeader]` attribute inside your model class.

Example model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "User-Agent")]
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
}
```

Example controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    ViewData["Agent"] = model.UserAgent;
    return View();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
    @ViewData["Agent"]
</div>
```